# Displaying a horizontal line and sum under column of a apex:pageblockTable

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

We need to display the following using Visualforce page from Account object and need to display the Sum/Total for the Columns Open Volume and Close Volume. I used  to display the 3 columns but finding it difficult to display the line and its sum for the columns Open Volume and Close Volume, can you please help.

[image: Account volume table]

I tried below code:

```
<apex:page controller="FetchData">
<style>
.ct
    {
        text-align:right;
    }
</style>
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account">                    
                <apex:column value="{!account.Name}" headerValue="Account Name" style="text-align: right;width:33%" headerClass="ct"/>
                <apex:column value="{!account.Open_Volume__c}" headerValue="Open Volume" style="text-align: right;width:33%" headerClass="ct">
                    <apex:facet name="footer"><hr noshade="noshade" width="8%" align="right"/>{!openVolumeSum}</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!account.Close_Volume__c }" headerValue="Close Volume" style="text-align: right;width:33%" headerClass="ct">                
                <apex:facet name="footer"><hr noshade="noshade" width="8%" align="right"/>{!closeVolumeSum}</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class FetchData 
{
    public List<Account> accounts{get;set;}
    public Decimal openVolumeSum{get;set;}
    public Decimal closeVolumeSum{get;set;}
    public FetchData()
    {
        openVolumeSum = 0;
        closeVolumeSum = 0; 
        accounts = [Select Name, Open_Volume__c, Close_Volume__c from Account Limit 10];
        if(accounts.size()>0)
        {
            for(Account acc: accounts)
            {
                openVolumeSum = openVolumeSum+acc.Open_Volume__c;
                closeVolumeSum = closeVolumeSum+ acc.Close_Volume__c ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and got below output:

[image]

As you see from the image, how do I align the totals(55 & 550) in line with the column values. I tried right align but it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your VF markup in the question?

Comment: Are you using Apex? You could loop through the records & increment two `Integer` variables for Open Volume and Close Volume based on the value in the loop.

Comment: With only apex:pageblockTable you can't add the bold lines. You have to use some div elements and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**Purely CSS** (Easiest)

```
<apex:page controller="myExample">

    <style>
        [id$=theTable]>tbody>tr:last-child td { border-top: solid 3px !important; }
    </style>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!theList}" id="theTable"  var="l">
            <apex:column headerValue="Value" value="{!l}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

[image: Just CSS Results]

A bit of a hack but also allows you to do it.

Basically I add a value to the end of my iterator to indicate it is the total row:

**Class**

```
public class myExample{

    public string[] theList {get;set;}

    public myExample(){
        theList = New String[]{'10','20','30','total'};
    }


}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myExample">

    <style>
        td.total_td{
            border-top: solid 3px !important; //make more selective to get rid of important

        }
    </style>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!theList}" var="l">
            <apex:column headerValue="Value" styleClass="{!if(l == 'total','total_td','')}">
                <apex:outPutPanel layout="none" rendered="{!l != 'total'}">
                    {!l}
                </apex:outPutPanel>
                <apex:outPutPanel layout="none" rendered="{!l == 'total'}">
                    60
                </apex:outPutPanel>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

[image: Results]

Feel free to modify as you see fit to make it al kinds of awesome

Comment: Ahem. `10 + 20 + 30 = 60`

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Ugh. Its early. Obviously I just typed it in...Will fix it though cause my ADD will not allow it to remain wrong

Comment: You can also make use of `first` and `last` attribute and use 2 pageBlockTable's, in first pageBlockTable `first={!theList.size - 1}` and in second one `last=1`. That might be more generic.

Comment: @RahulSharma I do not see a last attribute for page block table, although I guess you could use CSS to select the last TD

Comment: Ah you're right, correction, its `first` and `rows` attributes

Comment: @RahulSharma - rows just lets you limit the rows to a specific number. And first sets the starting index of the iteration. Its not an indication of if the current iteration is the last...but maybe it can be used to identify but I will have to ponder it a bit

Comment: Thankyou all for your response, I have updated the code I used and stuck in aligning the sum value to right, please help.

Comment: @Jaya - Please do not modify questions to be completely different from the original as the answers loos the context. Please start a new question. Also, if an answer solved the initial problem mark it accepted so others can find accepted answers

Answer (score 0):

you can use workaround 
`<table> <th> <tr> <td>` tag as per your need and last
 `<table><tr><span style="color:blue">sum<span></tr><tr>{!sumOfOpenVolume}</tr><tr>{!sumOfCloseVolume}</tr>`

Comment: or you can use <hr/> tag for lining thanks